# Comparing button background images

Tags: java, android, button, if-statement

I'm having trouble comparing button background images, this is the code I have

```
if (temp[0].getBackground() == temp[1].getBackground()) {

        ...
    }
```

So when I run the code and the backgrounds of temp[0] and temp[1] are from the same drawable it says that they aren't equal(==) to each other but if I did

```
if (temp[0].getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor() == temp[1].getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor()) {

        ...
    }
```

They would be equal to each other but if I had another button with a different drawable it passes as those also being equal which I don't want. How do I make an if statement to compare the background images of my buttons?

temp[] is an array containing Buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes down to: in Java, objects are compared using `.equals()` and not `==`; the later should be used only to compare primitives (`int`, `long`...etc) or object references.

Comment: if (temp[0].getBackground().equals(temp[1].getBackground()) )
is what you mean right? It still isn't working for me like it should. :\

Comment: If `getBackground()` is returning an object, then that's the way to go. If `equals()` is returning `false` it means that both objects have different values. What's `getBackground()`'s type?

I'm assuming you are using Swing, huh?

Comment: it returns a Drawable, I don't know what Swing is :(

Answer (score 0):

Use .equals().  The == operator only checks if the two references are the same.  The equals function compares the objects.  Assuming Android correctly implemented .equals, this should work.